# how to use active perl script for monitoring windows services

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, perl, windows-services

Has anybody written an ActivePerl script using [Win32::Service](http://p3rl.org/Win32%3a%3aService)?

If so, can you show me some sample code on how to call this? I know its says Win32, but would like to know if this would work also on a 64 bit machine. I'm primarily interested in checking the services status.

Comment: The API called "Win32" is in fact the same on both 32-bit and 64-bit machines. The name just signifies the difference from "Win16" or whatever Windows 3.x used.

Comment: Try this... http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=Simple%20WIN32%20Service%20Test

Comment: No problem. You might also want to look at Windows PowerShell for stuff like this.

Comment: @Joe- if you answer my question with your comment. I will mark it as my answer. thanks

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that. FYI, just in case you decide to look into PowerShell, or for other readers... http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332527.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a [basic example on PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=Simple%20WIN32%20Service%20Test) that you can check out. Be sure to read the comments, as there's a code modification that improves the results of the original code.